# openlayers import Map vs array Map

Tags: javascript, openlayers

Openlayers Map vs javascript's built-in Map object.

at https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/tree/master/package

the suggestion is that a new openlayers map can be created by using new Map({ // properties });

but how does one then also use the javascript built-in Map documented here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

?

if I want to use both in the same javascript, how is that done (ie: to differentiate them?)

thank you!
peter

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the OpenLayer's example code provided in the page you linked, they suggested doing the following:

```
import Map from 'ol/map';
```

Because the `Map` you are importing is a default export from the `ol/map` path, you can name it whatever you like in order to avoid any naming conflicts. For example, you could instead write.

```
import OLMap from 'ol/map';
```

and then use `new OLMap({...})` for the OpenLayers map while still being able to use `Map` for the built-in type.